# Outline div with a border css?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want to create a bounding box around the div with a grey border how do i do that Please help.

**Please find below my code:**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gyxpE

CSS:

```
  .box {
   border:2px solid #ECF0F1;
}
```

**I want to surround the row with a white border and so on and so forth**

Please find my code here : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gyxpE

Comment: if you mean the border for `.box`, so isn't that you've already had CSS style for it? it does not work? Anyway, it's unclear about the region (circumferenced by blue line in your image). You should talk about it, such as its id, its class... looking into your messy HTML code is not easy to start.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by a bounding box?

Comment: How about a jsFiddle showing the problem?

Comment: looks like wrappers are standing aside as columns and not rows , give us the whole picture html+css in a fiddle or codepen. we only have here code for the first left column ...

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gyxpE

Comment: @GCyrillus Have added my code in codepen

Comment: looks like we have to change the HTML code, however it looks messy to me, although the rendered page looks fairly great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I solved my issue:**

Used the following CSS:

```
   .box {
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
   border:2px solid #ECF0F1;
   margin:0;
}
```

Also removed all the margins from my CSS